# Slice query on TimeUUID columns

Tags: cassandra, uuid, slice

I've a cassandra db and column family with TimeUUIDType comparator. I use Hector and have keyspace using RandomPartitioner.

I'd like to make slice query to get pageable results ordered by TimeUUID.

```
SliceQuery<String, UUID, UserLike> query = HFactory.createSliceQuery(getKeyspace(), StringSerializer.get(), TimeUUIDSerializer.get(), UserLikesSerializer.get());
query = query.setKey(username);
query.setColumnFamily(SOME_CF);
```

When I configures a query with this code:

```
 query.setRange(new UUID(UUIDGen.createTime(Long.MAX_VALUE),UUIDGen.getClockSeqAndNode()), null, true, maxResults);
```

i retrieves data with incorrect sequence (probably because I use RandomPartitioner - correct?)
When I configures a query with this code:

```
query.setRange(new UUID(UUIDGen.createTime(Long.MAX_VALUE),UUIDGen.getClockSeqAndNode()), new UUID(UUIDGen.createTime(0),UUIDGen.getClockSeqAndNode()), true, maxResults);
```

i gets an error:

```
InvalidRequestException(why:range finish must come after start in the order of traversal)
at me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you're seeing this error because you need to use `getTimeUUIDBytes`, instead of `new UUID`; the latter just composes a uuid out of the two longs you give it, neither of which is "the timestamp" per se.  So:

```
query.setRange(UUIDGen.getUUID(UUIDGen.getTimeUUIDBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE)), null, true, maxResults);
```

More generally, you can just pass null, null as the start/end of the range when you just need to say "give me the first page of results" and not have to worry about this.

Comment: not exactly. Is was the problem with timespan (i mean value Long.MAX_VALUE). I replaced it with System.currentTimeInMillis() and now it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

This error is because that the start range is greater than the end range value in the query you used.